# Using `each` to check whether all values are the same

Tags: ruby, arrays

I'm trying to evaluate whether every space value is equal to either `"X"` or `"O"`. Can I use `each` to do that? Is there a better way?

```
if @spaces.each {|x| x=="O" || x=="X"}
    @winner = true
    puts "It's a tie!"
    break
end
```

ETA: `all?` doesn't seem to be working, either. I got this error referring to the line with the block:

```
tictac.rb:47: syntax error, unexpected '|', expecting '}'
        {|x| x=="O" || x=="X"}
          ^
tictac.rb:47: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting keyword_end
```

Here is the entire TicTacToe I'm working on:

```
class Board
def initialize
    @spaces = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
    self.print_board
    @winner = false
    @turn = "X"
end

def print_board 
    puts
    puts "    " + @spaces[0].to_s + " " + @spaces[1].to_s + " " + @spaces[2].to_s
    puts "    " + @spaces[3].to_s + " " + @spaces[4].to_s + " " + @spaces[5].to_s
    puts "    " + @spaces[6].to_s + " " + @spaces[7].to_s + " " + @spaces[8].to_s
    puts
end

def mark(turn, move)
   space = @spaces.index(move) 
   @spaces[space] = turn
   self.print_board
end

def play
      while @winner == false
    puts "where would you like to put your #{@turn}?"
    move = gets.chomp.to_i
    self.mark(@turn, move)
    if 
      @spaces[0] == @turn  && @spaces[1] == @turn && @spaces[2] == @turn ||
      @spaces[3] == @turn && @spaces[4] == @turn && @spaces[5] == @turn ||
      @spaces[6] == @turn && @spaces[7] == @turn && @spaces[8] == @turn ||
      @spaces[0] == @turn && @spaces[3] == @turn && @spaces[6] == @turn ||
      @spaces[1] == @turn && @spaces[4] == @turn && @spaces[7] == @turn ||
       @spaces[2] == @turn && @spaces[5] == @turn && @spaces[8] == @turn ||
       @spaces[0] == @turn && @spaces[4] == @turn && @spaces[8] == @turn ||
        @spaces[2] == @turn && @spaces[4] == @turn && @spaces[6] == @turn 

        @winner = true
        puts "#{@turn} is the winner!"
        break
    elsif @spaces.all? 
        {|x| x=="O" || x=="X"}
        @winner = true
        puts "It's a tie!"
        break
    else
        @turn == "X"? @turn = "O" : @turn = "X"
    end
    end
    end
end

game = Board.new 
game.play
```

I marked an answer that worked, and I guess `all?` was better than my `each`, but I'm still curious why changing it to `all?` didn't seem to work.

Comment: `if @spaces.all?{ |x| x=="O" || x=="X" }`

Comment: or `@spaces.all?{ |space| %w<X O>.include? space }`

Comment: `all?` works fine: `["O", "X", "X", "O"].all? { |x| x=="O" || x=="X" } => true`.

Comment: Don't put a newline between `all?` and its block. Ruby thinks you're calling `all?` without a block and defining a hash on the next line.

Comment: There is ambiguity in the text of the question. The title resolves it in one way, and the answer you accepted resolves the ambiguity in another way. Do you want to check if (a) the elements are either all `"X"` or all `"O"`, or (b) whether each element is either `"X"` or `"O"`?

Comment: Technically I wanted to check if they're either "X" or "O", but basically I was trying to figure out whether .each with a block would work for this...if it would work for matching one value, I figured it would work for my or statement.

Comment: Ironically, I phrased it like that because I figured that that was a more general question that was applicable to my problem in an attempt to follow the rules about asking useful general questions.

Comment: Just as a nit; if folks are going to downvote questions, especially questions from newcomers, please give some rationale in the Comments section, so they can improve their questions in the future!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All elements of `@spaces` will be `"O"` or `"X"` if

```
(@spaces - ["O", "X"]).empty?
```

is true.

```
@spaces = ["O", "X", "X", "O"]
(@spaces - ["O", "X"]).empty?
  #=> true

@spaces = ["O", "X", "X", "O", "cat"]
(@spaces - ["O", "X"]).empty?
  #=> false
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I understand why it was. There is ambiguity in the question.

Comment: @sawa, please enlighten me.  What alternative interpretation am I missing?

Comment: I commented to the question. Your interpretation is not the one that fits with the question title.

Comment: I see. Thanks. I guess someone thought I should have answered the Y (the title) rather than the X (the first sentence). Fair enough.

Answer (score 2):

```
@spaces.all? { |x| x=="O" || x=="X" }
```

You cannot put a newline between a method call and its block. That makes Ruby think you're calling the method without a block and defining a Hash.

Comment: This is a very helpful answer and solves the fundamental mistake that I was making.

Answer (score -1):

### Chain Array#Uniq and Array#Size

Refactor your check into a method which takes an array of box entries (e.g. "X" or "O"), or a variable holding such an array. The method will return true if all letters in the array are the same, because there will only be one unique character. For example:

```
def check_spaces letters
  true if letters.uniq.size == 1
end

check_spaces %w[X X X] #=> true
check_spaces %w[O O O] #=> true
check_spaces %w[O X O] #=> nil
```

If you do this, you can even assign the result of #check_spaces directly to *@winner*, like so:

```
@winner = check_spaces %w[X X X]
#=> true

@winner = check_spaces %w[X O X]
#=> nil
```